# Background repeat only left side

Tags: html, css, background

Need Help for repeat background only in left side i had review some example for that but there is apply width in % if possible without width in % or pixel

My content width is 800px and center of screen. want to left side background color repeat in all screen.

Comment: repeat vertical on background for left content element. Should fill width and repeat height..

Comment: I am not getting your problem. Can your explain more?

Comment: I want repeat blue background in left side in all screen and content is center

Comment: [here][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat] ... [and here] [http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3868361] ... [and here][http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-repeat]

Comment: When you say you want to "repeat blue background in left side in all screen" what do you mean? You would like the whole screen to repeat the blue background? I'm, not clear.

Comment: not whole screen it will be only left side part

Comment: What have you tried? I see your demo, but what about an example on applying a background repeat rule in your css? Even a broken example that you would expect to work, otherwise we are just doing the research for you, such as in the given links in my previous comment

Comment: Thank you All i had solve my issue once gain Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea of what you want but you may be leaving details out of your question. You said that you want the left side of the screen to repeat background blue but you already have:

```
 #left
{
  width 250px;
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  float:left;   
  background:#0CF;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Seems like you would like the "gap" or the white space next to your blue div to be filled in. A good thing to try is using a percentage or em in your left div similar to:

```
#left
{
  width:52%;
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  float:left;   
  background:#0CF;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

If you use a fix width (i.e width:250px) you will always have a gap or white space. since the width is fixed. Hope this helps